# Use Storage.writeObject with a Runnable in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

In Codename One, a code like the following doesn't compile:

```
Runnable r = (Runnable & Serializable)() -> Log.p("Serializable!");
```

I get:

```
error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getImplMethodKind()
  location: interface SerializedLambda
```

Is there any way to write a `Runnable` to the Storage? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Unlike Java serialization we don't write `Class` data only the data of the object. Since the bytecode is transpiled to native platforms there's no applicable class data to write. We also don't support the `Serializable` interface, only our version of `Externalizable` which isn't compatible.

You can write something based on that but it won't be as pretty as you need to create a regular class. That's because we can't use reflection voodoo to load an oddly structured class dynamically.